# Redis slow query with pipelined hgetall

Tags: python, performance, redis, database-performance, query-performance

So I have a small and simple Redis database. It contains 136689 keys whose values are hash maps containing 27 fields. I'm accessing the table through the Python interface on the server node, and need to load about 1000-1500 values per call (eventually I will see around 10 requests per second). A simple call looks something like this:

```
# below keys is a list of approximately 1000 integers, 
# not all of which are in the table

import redis
db = redis.StrictRedis(
  host='127.0.0.1',
  port=6379,
  db=0,
  socket_timeout=1,
  socket_connection_timeout=1,
  decode_responses=True
)

with db.pipeline() as pipe:
  for key in keys: 
    pipe.hgetall(key)
  results = zip(keys,pipe.execute())
```

The overall time for this is ~328ms with an average time per request of ~0.25ms.

> **Question:** This is very slow for a small database and relatively few queries per second. Is there something wrong with my configuration or the way I'm calling the server? Can something be done to make this faster? I don't expect the table to get much bigger so I'm perfectly happy sacrificing disk space for speed.

---

## Additional Information

Calling `hget` on each key (without the pipeline) is slower (as expected) and reveals the the time distribution is bimodal. The smaller peak corresponds to keys that are not in the table and the bigger one corresponds to keys that are.

[image: Redis response time distribution]

My conf file is as follows:

```
port 6379
daemonize yes 
save ""
bind 127.0.0.1
tcp-keepalive 300 
dbfilename mytable.rdb
dir .
rdbcompression yes 

appendfsync no
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite yes 
loglevel notice
```

I launch the server with:

```
> echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
> redis-server myconf.conf
```

I've also measured the intrinsic latency with `redis-cli --intrinsic-latency 100` which gives:

```
Max latency so far: 1 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 10 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 11 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 12 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 18 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 32 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 34 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 38 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 48 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 52 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 60 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 75 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 94 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 120 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 281 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 413 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 618 microseconds.

1719069639 total runs (avg latency: 0.0582 microseconds / 58.17 nanoseconds per run).
Worst run took 10624x longer than the average latency.
```

This suggests that I should be able to get much better latency. However, when I check the server latency with: `> redis-cli --latency -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379` I get `min: 0, max: 2, avg: 0.26 (2475 samples)`

This seems to suggest that ~0.25ms is the latency for my server, but that seems suggest that the latency per request I'm seeing from Python is the same as the CLI, but it all seems very very slow.

The hashmap associated to each key (after decoding) has a size of ~1200 bytes. So I ran the following benchmark

```
redis-benchmark -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -d 1500 hmset hgetall myhash rand_int rand_string
====== hmset hgetall myhash rand_int rand_string ======
  100000 requests completed in 1.45 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  1500 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

100.00% <= 1 milliseconds
100.00% <= 1 milliseconds
69060.77 requests per second
```

This seems to support that my latency is very high, but doesn't really tell me why.

Comment: @Paul, Based on your code, I see that you're not making multiple network calls. You're using Redis pipelines to make a single network call and sending all the keys as part of the same call. So I don't think network is the bottleneck here. Here are a couple of ideas that you can try out: Do you want to 'getall' the attributes for a given key. If not, you can get specific attributes with 'hget'. If you want all the keys (also if you don't want to filter based on attributes), then why not dump the entire object as a JSON in a Set, which you can retrieve based on the key and deserialise yourself.

Comment: @kayvis You're right, there is no network call just interprocess communication. I do need all of the keys and tried storing serialized json and gzipped json in the field so that I could use get rather than hgetall and deserialize myself, but it didn't help.

Comment: I see your redis-benchmark run with 1500 bytes which translates to 1.5 kb. Is that the size of all the 27 field values put together? I'm just trying to see if we're making apples to apples comparison when we compare benchmark's results to our actual results. Also, when you say 'but it didn't help', what do you mean? Are the results pretty much the same? If so, are you measuring the time including the gunzip and Json deserialisation or excluding them?

Comment: @kayvis 1.5kb is all fields together. Yes, the results are pretty much the same regarding just the Redis portion of the code, it helps a little but not enough to get to what one might call "low latency". I did not factor in the time for my own gunzip/deserialization. That said, the compression is very low so not much is gained by gzip.

Answer (score 2):

One of the conclusion that I got from the way I was using Redis is that we should not store each transaction inside one hash. As in one transaction one hash.

For each hget request we have a network connexion that is slowing the query down.

I think the way Redis is design it would be faster to store everything inside one hash, As in all transaction under the same hash.

Furthermore the granular data could be store in each key:values as JSON.

The time I got to retrieve all hashes vs the time I got from retrieving all values stored inside one hash is for 140mb worth of data:

- 3 seconds of iterating each hash and getting its key:values
  vs
- 0,008 seconds for getting one hash and then searching a key:value inside that hash,
  vs
- 0,008 seconds to get all data stored under one hash.

Instead of having 1 000 000 000 iteration (if you have 1 000 000 000 hashes) in your for iteration, here with the proposed solution you only have 1 (more if you can segregate your data based on an intrinsic value), hence reducing significantly the query time.

Comment: As per the code, OP's not making a network call for each 'hget'. He's using Redis 'pipelining' to do a bulk get. This is similar to 'mget' in sets.

Comment: Also, can you be a bit more clear on 'all transactions in one hash'?

Comment: Let's say you have cars, instead of storing car one under index 1, car 2 under index 2 and so on, and within each index you have all the key value pairs (motor brand : "Mercedows", "horse power":"355") related to the car in key and value pairs inside the index 1. So instead of having each car inside one index, you create an index cars, inside car you can have your key:values system, each car can be indexed by number and inside the value you would have all values for that car dumped inside a json. Getting all cars is just hmget('cars') instead of looping through all indexes inside your db.

Comment: regarding the network calls the pipeline does not significantly changes the time to get all keys and their values. let's say you have 1 thousand keys, you will be stuck for ages, whereas having them all under one 1 key will give you almost an instant response.

Comment: Storing combinations in a single hash would balloon the table size as I don't know which combinations I need ahead of time. In this case there is no network call per-se as everything is on the same box.

Comment: I think what @Pelican is suggesting is that you can probably store multiple entries under a single hash key, instead of having one. For instance, you could theoretically store 1000 items in one key which will utilize about 27000 fields instead of just 27, and that will reduce key cardinality from 136689 to only 136.

Comment: Here is an article from Instagram engineering team which took suggestions from redis's core developer to improve performance & reduce space usage. https://instagram-engineering.com/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs-in-redis-1091ae80f74c